# Train single Keras model.variable with Tensorflow GradientTape()

Tags: tensorflow, keras, backpropagation

I am currently working on implementing a Radial Basis Function Network (RBFN) in Keras/ Tensorflow. Ive set up my own RBF Layer in Keras and now I want to write my own training routine using `tf.GradientTape()`. My Keras model has a set of three different variables (center, width, weight) for the RBF activation. Since i want to write a training routine with network growing and prunin strategies i need to calculate the the gradient of a single RBF w.r.t to the loss.

Im using Tensorflow 2.0.0 and python 3.7.4

If I pass in all my `model.trainable_variables` into the `tf.GradientTape().gradients()` function everything works fine. My routine would look like this:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as t:
    y_hat = model(X)
    current_loss   = loss(y_hat, y)
    grads = t.gradient(current_loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
```

My goal is to apply the gradients only to the nearest (by the center parameter) located RBF neuron to the input `X[i]`

```
with tf.GradientTape() as t:
        y_hat = model(X[i])
        current_loss   = loss(y_hat, y[i])

        centers = model.trainable_variables[0]

        eucl = tf.math.abs(centers - X[i])                    # euclidian distance of input to RBF centers              
        idx_nr = tf.math.argmin(tf.math.abs(eucl)).numpy()[0] # idx of nearest RBF

        grads = t.gradient(current_loss, model.trainable_variables[0][idx_nr]) # just the centers
        print(grads)
```

However this always returns `None` for the gradients. Does `t.gradient()` expect the variables to be in a specific format? I hope you guys can come up with some good ideas. Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: What's `e_n` here? You have `current_loss` in the first example.

Comment: sorry `e_n` is `current_loss`. i forgot to change it. but the the error remains.